# Trouble with ssh / https while using npm and git

Tags: git, github, ssh, https

so I'm trying to use `npm i --save-dev somePackage`

but as I hit enter this shows up:

```
/usr/local/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/babel/preset-react.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in
```

I'm not quite sure whats happening here, I'm guessing using ssh and need a key but I don't want to do that and I want a regular push pull commit work flow so I guessing it would be https?

If thats the case how can I revert or delete and start a new? I habe tried multiple commands and even githubs documentation but I can't seem to make it work?

UPDATE : found to change URL i need to do this command check first current url

```
git remote -v
```

then `git remote set-url https://source/user/repo/.git`

but after doing that and typing in `git remote -v`
nothing has changed?

Answer (score 1):

> but after doing that and typing in git remote -v nothing has changed?

That is because the correct command would be:

```
git remote set-url origin https://source/user/repo/.git
                   ^^^^^^
```

But if you want to force npm to use HTTPS for *all* dependencies URLs, you can also use:

```sh
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```